# Horizontal scroll for grid view

Tags: android, gridview, horizontal-scrolling

In android how to create a grid type view that is scroll in horizontal way.
basically my requirement is to create a grid view and at top of screen, two button for next/previous.
when user clicks on next/previous button page is scroll in horizontal way.

How to create such type of view.please help me.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use Jess Anders' two-way-gridview available on github: https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview

Comment: @Sherif elKhatib sir,thanks for reply. by using link i am able to show view as i require but finding some issue in it. 1. how to scroll view on click of button.is this possible to scroll view on button click event.  and 2. How to manage no. of columns  i have sated   app:numColumns="3" but in large device it show 4 columns.

Comment: @Sherif elKhatib i have imported  two-way-gridview libraries from git now what should i do?